# Is a comma needed?

Tags: commas, comma-splices

My question is if a comma is needed before *and* in the sentence below. Is there a better way to join these two thoughts other than to use a comma?

> A court may choose to not invalidate such a statute **and** instead hold
>   that certain applications are unconstitutional.

For example, would this be a proper way to join these sentences without a conjunction?

> A court may choose to not invalidate such a statute, instead holding
>   that certain applications are unconstitutional.

Comment: I assume you mean 'statute'; otherwise, either is fine.

Comment: You could also put a comma before "and" and after "instead," but I suspect doing so would be more appropriate for speaking than writing (since in speaking, the commas tend to emphasize the contrast between choosing and holding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically, the sentence was fine (except for the unnecessarily split infinitive) as first written.  Here you have a single subject with a compound verb:  COURT MAY CHOOSE AND HOLD.  The comma-conjunction joining you asked about would be used where there is a second full clause.

Answer (score 0):

> Block quote

A court may choose to not invalidate such a statute, holding instead that certain applications are unconstitutional.

> Block quote

Just a small reflow.